# Typo3 - Multiple page templates

Tags: templates, typo3

I am very new to Typo3, and I have a very basic (not to say dumb) question: is it possible to have multiple page templates or can you only have one template?

What I need to do is have different templates call different scripts because apparently having the same template call all of them seems to create conflicts.

Thank you for your help!

Jane

Comment: The answer is almost certainly yes, but we'll need you to tell us a few things to get specific...  Are you using TemplaVoila? What's the script that "creates conflicts"?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, jalefkowit. Yes, we are using TemplaVoila, but I actually just realized we were calling two different jQuery libraries and that was probably what was causing the conflict. We upgraded everything to jQuery 1.4.2 and that seems to have sesolved a number of issues. Many thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can have many different templates on a site. Actually each single page can have its very own template. You might be interested in checking out templavoila since its very graphical and once you got it set up, you can easily change between templates within the Typo3 backend.

[Tutorials](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/tutorials/doc_tut_ftb1/1.0.1/view/)

An alternative would be to use the original TypoScript templates which is not difficult yet requires a bit of TypoScript understanding.

[TypoScript Templates](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tstemplates/current/)

In any way you can chose between different templates.

Answer (score 1):

Using TypoScript, you can include any number of scripts in your template.

You can even imagine the following page tree:

-Home
--Page 1
--Page 2
---Page A
---Page B
--Page 3

You can set a certain template for the homepage, and it will apply to all pages. But you can set a completely different template for page 3, and it will only apply to that page. You can also apply a slightly different template to page 2, overriding specific values (page background, CSS inclusion, etc), and it will apply to Page A and Page B as well.